# Paperclip and ImageMagick, convert_options -border

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, imagemagick, paperclip

I've got a Project model which has an attached file, I've defined few styles and it uploads to S3.

I want to create a style that add borders to the image in order to respect 4/3 format.

I've found :convert_options and I'm doing this:

```
:styles=> {
      :one => "700x330!",
      :two => "700x330!"
    },
    :convert_options => {
      :two => "-bordercolor #000000 -border 10x10",
    }
```

But when I try to open my image with :two style, it says that there was an error loading the Jpeg file.
Here's the error :

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Improper call to JPEG library in
>   state 200)

When I look in S3, the file that I uploaded is 0 bytes weight.

It works perfectly with other styles so I guess I'm doing something wrong with :convert_options.

Can you please help me fix this ?
Cordially, Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding my convert options in a array like this :

```
:convert_options => {
                      :flux => ["-bordercolor black","-border 10x10"]
                    }
```